# French passive after relative pronouns

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs, passif

When using the passive voice, is there a specific rule for after relative pronouns — is it *qui* with *être* or *que* with *on* and *avoir*?

For example, take “*he wanted to find his car which had been stolen*”:

> Il voulait trouver sa voiture qu'on avait volée.
>
> Il voulait trouver sa voiture qui avait été volée.

Is there a more grammatically correct version of this, or can both be used with the same effect?

Comment: Your first example **isn't** passive. It's saying, "He wanted to find his car which **someone had stolen**". Only your second example is passive: "He wanted to find his car which **had been stolen**".

Comment: Both are correct - I'm not so sure about the punctuation, though. Except for the spelling mistake : _qu'on avait volée_, feminine. Oh, and one more thing : it sounds more natural to use _retrouver_ instead of _trouver_.

Comment: Better yet, if I may. Il voulait retrouver la voiture qu'on lui avait volée.

Comment: Indeed, only your second setence is passive. If you want to use the passive voice, it's the only correct version. As Nomaru said, it sounds better with "retrouver".

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but in an effort to avoid even the (phonetic) appearance of (sounding) “con,” I usually try to remember to replace “qu’on” with “que l’on.”  However, I find your use of “qu’on” when discussing a car thief to be rather clever and entirely justified! +1

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing here is 'case', a concept used to a greater extent in Latin, German, Russian or Arabic, but only shows up in French on a few pronouns. This concept refers to the role of a noun in a sentence. Just like *il* has the counterparts *le*, *en* and *lui*, so we can say *qui* has the counterparts *que*, *dont* and then a load of *preposition + lequel* formulas. Indeed in some languages, they list this group as a declension of one word (normally starting with the equivalent of *qui*).

It's a case of choosing the right one, according to its role in the sentence. Don't forget that this series is officially called *relative pronouns* and that they are all therefore essentially nouns that represent something in a phrase (which is joined to an earlier phrase). If you want to make it easier, cut the second phrase off just before the *qui/que/dont/auquel...* and ask yourself what it represents.

*qu'on avait volé* : well, *on* is already the doer, the thief, so the car, the thing stolen, the accusative is represented by *que*.

*qui avait été volée* : by chosing a passive, you risk getting confused, as it involves putting a logical object (the thing stolen) as the grammatical subject (the thing doing a verb), but because here the car commands the verb it becomes *qui*.

*qui porte une plaque marocaine* : is easier, because the car is obviously the doer, the carrier so takes *qui* (just as you could replace it with *il/elle*).

*dont les vitres sont cassées* : here *dont* replaces *de la voiture*.

*à laquelle il avait dédié sa vie* : we're now going further down the series into the prepositional options, but same again, *à laquelle* represents *à la voiture*.

Answer (score 1):

La question n'est pas en relation avec la forme passive  mais est une règle d'usage générale du pronom relatif:
**Qui** est sujet du verbe, 
**Que**, élidé **qu'**, est complément du verbe.

La voiture **qu'**  on avait volée
*...**qu'** est complément du verbe *avait volée*.
La voiture **qui** avait été volée: **qui**, mis pour la voiture, est le sujet du verbe *avait été volée*, forme passive.

Mais cela s'applique dans tous les cas d'emploi de pronom relatif:
J'ai bien aimé le livre **que** tu m'as prêté.
J'ai bien aimé le livre **qui** a reçu le prix Médicis cette année.